# file_get_contents failed to open chinese website

Tags: php, html, dom, curl, character-encoding

I was working on a script to extract HTML source from a Chinese website.
I tried **file_get_contents** to read the web file,

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
echo $html;
```

Below is the result obtained,

[image]

I found the **content type** in my target website as ,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312" />
```

So I tried converting result to utf-8,

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://newhouse.bt.soufun.com/house/web/Search_Result.php');
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html,'utf-8','GB2312'); 
echo $html;
```

The result is now showing,

[image]

With the above options I could not get the proper source of the page and this could not be further parsed.I need to parse the HTML and get structured data out of it using a DOM parser. Here I am getting a malformed HTML response which could not be further parsed.

I tried file_get_contents as well as CURL.

I am currently stuck at this point and any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Don't just assume the source encoding, Eastern nations use all kinds of encodings that are more convenient for their alphabets. `$html = mb_convert_encoding($html,'utf-8',mb_detect_encoding ($html));` I don't think that's your problem though, it looks like you're getting binary content back

Comment: @GordonM Yes my problem was on the binary content back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly the site is returning you the compressed content. So decode it. You can use [gzdecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) of php if you want.

Alternately you can use curl to get the compressed content and decode automatically:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");  // handling all compressions
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print $result;
```

Comment: +1 for curl, url_fopen just doesn't cut it in a lot of cases.

Comment: Thanx a lot...! It worked.But the results were showing special characters like,�ѷ���ҳ | ��Ѷ | �·� ���ַ� �ⷿ | װ�޼Ҿ� | ҵ����̳ | �ز����� | �ֻ��ѷ�

After adding the following code to it,worked perfectly.
$result = mb_convert_encoding($result,'utf-8','GB2312');

Comment: @Surabhil Like I commented on your question you should use mb_detect_encoding rather than just assume GB2312

Comment: @GordonM Thanks for that advice. Is there a possibility that 'GB2312' would change.I saw the same with many pages on the site.

Comment: There's always a possibility that data coming from an outside source could change at any point.